# Embedding vlookup formulas into excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to create a macro that will embed multiple `VLOOKUP` formulas into specific cells in a worksheet that is run as new document every week. I tried using the formula function but I keep getting a run time error 13 message - type mismatch.

The formula is below

```
Sub FORMULA()
    Range("EG21").FORMULA = "=iferror(VLOOKUP(DY21,EVCargo!D:BG,56,0)," - ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: you need double quotation marks within the string: `"=iferror(VLOOKUP(DY21,EVCargo!D:BG,56,0),"" - "")"` - AND you should not name a sub using a VBA-code word

Answer (score 0):

That's because of "-". It sets as formula included in first pair of quotation marks. And first pair of them ends when starts "-", so only this if regarded as formula and `"=iferror(VLOOKUP(DY21,EVCargo!D:BG,56,0),"`
Change "-" with 0, for example, and it will work, I guess.
Or write it as  `Range("EG21").FORMULA ="=iferror(VLOOKUP(DY21,EVCargo!D:BG,56,0),"&Chr(34)&"-"&Chr(34)&")"`
Chr(34) will return quotation mark